# IIS with ASP MVC vs nginx with php preformance

Tags: php, nginx, iis, asp.net

I'm wondering what does asp mvc performance look like in comparison with php on nginx. IIS itself is much more demanding than nginx. But does it start to benefit at some amount of users?

1) Let's say I have a machine 1.6GHz and 1.75GB RAM (parameters form the smallest reserved hosting on Azure). Will they perform similarly? How many viewers will be required to balance the initial IIS requirements?

2) Let's now talk about a normal shared hosting offered by e.q. GoDaddy. Having the same plan, will there be a significant difference of the amount of users I'll be able to serve?

Of course we assume that the functionality of both apps is the same. E.q. a big internet shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NginX and IIS have very similar architecture. The PHP/C# workers runs in separate process than IIS. C# is much faster than PHP, and IIS on Windows is at least as twice as fast as NginX on the same machine. Simply Microsoft blows up all Open Source, also it has better security out of the box, and NginX/PHP you need to secure with SELinux, AppArmor yourself.

Comment: Advocating microsoft feels truly evil. Debunking open source even more!